# Forming a 'partial' identity-matrix according to a partially filled vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I'm currently forming a matrix from a vector in MATLAB following the scheme described below:

Given is a vector `x` containing ones and zeros in an arbitrary order, e.g.

```
x = [0 1 1 0 1];
```

From this, I would like to form a matrix `Y` that is described as follows:

- `Y` has `m` rows, where `m` is the number of ones in `x` (here: `3`).
- Each row of `Y` is filled with a one at the `k`-th entry, where `k` is the position of a one in vector `x` (here: `k = 2,3,5`)
- For the example `x` from above, this would result in:

  ```
  Y = [0 1 0 0 0;
       0 0 1 0 0; 
       0 0 0 0 1]
  ```

  This is identical to an identity matrix, that has its (`x=0`)th rows eliminated.

I'm currently achieving this via the following code:

```
x = [0,1,1,0,1]; %example from above
m = sum(x==1);
Y = zeros(m,numel(x));
p = 1;
for n = 1:numel(x)
    if x(n) == 1 
       Y(p,n) = 1;
       p = p+1;
    end  
end
```

It works but I'm kind of unhappy with it as it seems rather inefficient and inelegant. Any ideas for a smoother implementation, maybe using some matrix multiplications or so are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few one-line alternatives:

- Using [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

  ```
  Y = full(sparse(1:nnz(x), find(x), 1));
  ```
- Similar but with [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

  ```
  Y = accumarray([(1:nnz(x)).' find(x(:))], 1);
  ```
- Using [`eye`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) and indexing. This assumes `Y` is previously undefined:

  ```
  Y(:,logical(x)) = eye(nnz(x));
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to obtain the indices of ones in `x` which are also the column subscripts of ones in `Y`. Find the number of rows of `Y` by [adding](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) all the elements of the vector `x`. Use these to initialise `Y` as a [zero matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html). Now find the linear indices to place 1s using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). [Use these indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to change the elements of `Y` to 1.

```
cols = find(x);
noofones = sum(x);
Y = zeros(noofones, size(x,2));
Y(sub2ind(size(Y), 1:noofones, cols)) = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative using matrix multiplications:

```
x = [0,1,1,0,1];
I = eye(numel(x));

% construct identity matrix with zero rows
Y = I .* x;   % uses implicit expansion from 2016b or later
Y = Y(logical(x), :);   % take only non-zero rows of Y
```

Result:

```
Y =
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1
```

Thanks to @SardarUsama's comment for simplifying the code a bit.

Comment: How about `Y = Y(logical(x), :);` instead of `Y = Y(logical(I*x.'), :);`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for the nice alternatives! I tried out all your solutions and averaged execution times over 1e4 executions for random (1000-entry) x-vectors. Here are the results:

1. (7.3e-4 sec) `full(sparse(1:nnz(x), find(x), 1));`
2. (7.5e-4 sec) `cols = find(x);
                noofones = sum(x);
                Y = zeros(noofones, size(x,2));
                Y(sub2ind(size(Y), 1:noofones, cols)) = 1;`
3. (7.7e-4 sec) `Y = accumarray([(1:nnz(x)).' find(x(:))], 1);`
4. (1.7e-3 sec) `I = speye(numel(x));
                Y = I .* x; 
                Y = full(Y(logical(x), :));`
5. (3.1e-3 sec) `Y(:,logical(x)) = eye(nnz(x));`

Answer (score 1):

From your comment "This is identical to an identity matrix, that has its (x=0)th rows eliminated.", well, you can also explicitly generate it as such:

```
Y = eye(length(x));
Y(x==0, :) = [];
```

Very slow option for long `x`, but it works slightly faster than `full(sparse(...` for `x` with 10 elements on my computer.